# Can the direction of wall nut bounce be controlled?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

In level 1-5 you are tasked to bowl with Wall Nuts, to take out zombies.  I see that the wall nuts bounce, but they seem to bounce randomly.  It seems like it is important to get multiple hits with each Wall Nut, but I can't figure out how to make it bounce up vs. down.  Can it be controlled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my own experience, you can't control which way it bounces.

From plantsvszombies wiki:

> ...the Wall-nut will bounce off at an angle, possibly hitting more
>   Zombies before it rolls off the screen. It will also only bounce off
>   towards the right as it does not make sense for it to go backwards...

It says nothing about which direction it bounds, up or down, so my guess is that it's somehow random.

Comment: Well, it'll never bounce off screen, so if it's on the top lane it'll always bounce down and vice versa :P

Answer (score 4):

I noticed while I played it has the chance to bounce up or down. This is the chart: 1st lane 100% chance of bouncing down. 2nd lane 75% chance to bounce down 25% chance to bounce up. 3rd lane 50% chance to bounce up and down. 4th lane 75% chance to bounce up 25% chance to bounce down. 5th lane 100% chance to bounce up. (Note: this chart is from wiki fandom)